# Bypass warnings in NetSuite SOAP request

Tags: soap, integration, netsuite

We are trying to create Invoices in NetSuite using a SOAP request. However, some of the Invoices don't get created because of warnings thrown in NetSuite. The response XML contains a "warning" node and a warning message. When doing manually through UI, we would just press "OK" to accept this warning and go ahead with Invoice creation. How do I bypass these warnings when doing through SOAP?

Comment: Do you mind sharing the error message with us? I had a similar issue once and we had to enable a NetSuite feature to remove the warning message. But this was case specific.

Comment: Hi @venkaraeaman,
how did you are creating an invoice for those customer who doesn't have credit limit, i am facing issue, i would appreciate if you can share with me some detail

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686093/how-to-create-invoice-in-netsuite-using-suitetalk

Answer (score 0):

Check out the NetSuite docs here https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N3536574.html.

It says warnings will either be treated as errors, or ignored when performing requests via their SOAP api.

There is also a boolean setting you can include in the request preferences called `warningAsError`.

E.g.

```
    <ns1:preferences xmlns:ns1="urn:messages_2022_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0">
      <ns1:warningAsError>false</ns1:warningAsError>
      <ns1:ignoreReadOnlyFields>true</ns1:ignoreReadOnlyFields>
```